# How can I credit a commenter with giving the right answer?

Tags: support

In my recent StackOverflow question, I got an immediate answer in a comment.

There was an interesting and useful actual answer later, but I felt the credit should go to the commenter.  I invited him to give an answer, but he didn't.  So I put in an answer saying his comment should get the credit.  But if I choose that one, or the other one, then he won't get the credit.

Comment: If someone else answered then you can accept their answer instead. You don't have to credit anyone, it's their choice whether to post a comment and not an answer

Comment: The most you can do is upvote their comment.

Answer (score 14):

First, a clarification: comments cannot be answers.

You might disagree with that, saying that the comment did, in fact, answer your question. The point remains, though, that as part of the design of the system, *comments cannot be answers*. That means there's no way to give "answer" credit to anyone based upon a comment.

The best you can do is what you already did: reply to the user who left the comment, say that his/her comment solved your problem, and encourage him/her to post an answer. Users are, however, free to decline, and there are a variety of reasons why they might do so. If they decline, then you should interpret that as their *opting out* of getting "answer" credit.

If you still think that their comment was helpful and you want to promote it to an answer for the benefit of future readers, then posting an answer of your own is the proper course of action. In your answer, you should give "credit" to the person who posted their comment by [mentioning them by name and citing their comment](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), just like you would for an answer. This won't give them any reputation, but see above.

As far as selecting ("accepting", in our vernacular) an answer, you should pick the one that you found *most* useful in solving your problem. Try not to think of rewards/reputation as the primary motivating factor here. The principal concern should be indicating to future users which answer you, the asker, found most useful. If that means the one you posted, then so be it.